# Combing 2D list of tuples and then sorting them in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

Update: The list are filled with strings I edited the list to show this

I have 3 different list such as

```
Section = [('1', '1.1', '1.2'), ('1', '2', '2.2', '3'), ('1', '1.2', '3.2', '3.5')] 
Page = [('1', '1', '3'), ('1', '2', '2', '2'), ('1', '2', '3', '5')]
Titles = [('General', 'Info', 'Titles'), ('More', 'Info', 'Section', 'Here'), ('Another', 'List', 'Of', 'Strings')]
```

I want to combine them such as

```
Combined_List = [('1', '1.1', '1.2'), ('1', '2', '2.2', '3'), ('1', '1.2', '3.2', '3.5'),
                 ('1', '1', '3'), ('1', '2', '2', '2'), ('1', '2', '3', '5'),  
                 ('General', 'Info', 'Titles'), ('More', 'Info', 'Section', 'Here'), ('Another', 'List', 'Of', 'Strings')]
```

Or any other form that allows me to then sort them by the numbers in the list titled sections.

In this case it would be

```
  Sorted_list = [('1', '1', '1', '1.1', '1.2', '1.2', '2', '2.2', '3', '3.2', '3.5'), 
                 ('1', '1', '1', '1', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '5'),
                 ('General', 'More', 'Another', 'Info', 'Titles', 'List', 'Info', 'Section', 'Here', 'Of', 'Strings')
```

I need it like this so I can eventually export a sorted list by Section into excel. If you can think of a better way to display/format please do share!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
Section = [('1', '1.1', '1.2'), ('1', '2', '2.2', '3'), ('1', '1.2', '3.2', '3.5')] 
Page = [('1', '1', '3'), ('1', '2', '2', '2'), ('1', '2', '3', '5')]
Titles = [('General', 'Info', 'Titles'), ('More', 'Info', 'Section', 'Here'), ('Another', 'List', 'Of', 'Strings')]

# Flat a list of tuples into a list
l1 = [item for sublist in Section for item in sublist]
l2 = [item for sublist in Page for item in sublist]
l3 = [item for sublist in Titles for item in sublist]

# Python2, `zip` returns a list of tuples
#result = zip(*sorted(zip(l1, l2, l3), key=lambda x:float(x[0])))

# Python3, `zip` returns an iterator of tuples
result = list(zip(*sorted(zip(l1, l2, l3), key=lambda x:float(x[0]))))

print(result)
# Output
[   ('1', '1', '1', '1.1', '1.2', '1.2', '2', '2.2', '3', '3.2', '3.5'), 
    ('1', '1', '1', '1', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '5'), 
    ('General', 'More', 'Another', 'Info', 'Titles', 'List', 'Info', 'Section', 'Here', 'Of', 'Strings')]
```

Comment: When I print result it returns <zip object at 0x000000000B6A54C8>. Which is a location in memory, no? Why would it return this?

Comment: @Jstuff, since you use Python3, add `list` to the front of `zip(...)`. `zip` in Python3 returns an iterator. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for! Quick question though. In the data I'm working with it has decimals to the second decimal place so 1.10, 1.11, etc and it sorted this as 1, 1.1, 1.10, 1.1, etc. Is there a way to tell python to sort it as 1.1, 1.2, ..., 1.9, 1.10, etc?

Comment: @Jstuff, good question. Split a number into the integer and decimal parts, use `zip` to pack them, sort them and integrate them.

Comment: Bear with me I'm still new to python. I tried doing l1_float = [float(i) for i in l1], but it drops the zero off of 1.10 so it sorts it has 1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2 instead of 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.10.0 Is there a better way to do this so it keeps the trailing zeros? Also, why do you float the value you pass into into lambda?

Comment: @Jstuff, I just posted a new question, [How do I sort a list of section numbers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595703/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-section-numbers-in-python).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113656/discussion-between-jstuff-and-sparkandshine).

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
from itertools import chain

tuples = zip(map(float, list(chain(*Section))), 
             list(chain(*Page)), 
             list(chain(*Title)))

zip(*sorted(tuples, key=lambda x: x[0]))

Out[232]:
[(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 2.0, 2.2, 3.0, 3.2, 3.5),
 ('1', '1', '1', '1', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '5'),
 ('General',
  'More',
  'Another',
  'Info',
  'Titles',
  'List',
  'Info',
  'Section',
  'Here',
  'Of',
  'Strings')]
```

Here you first unnest your three list (what `list(chain(*L))` does) and pack them in tuples with `zip`. Tip "tuples" to see how it looks.

Then on the second line of code you can apply the sorting according to the element of the tuple you want. And you unpack the result.

Comment: I forgot to inlcude in the original code that the list are filled with strings. I have updated the post to show this. I tried your method and then printed the value of tuples and the second line in the code. They returned <zip object at 0x000000000B0E2488> and
<zip object at 0x000000000B0E2448> respectively. These are locations in memory correct? Did this happen because they are actually strings?

Comment: I updated my answer to take into account the fact you have strings.

Comment: When I print the list I still get <zip object at 0x000000000B84F848>
<zip object at 0x000000000B84F708>. Not sure why...

Comment: I guess it is due to python version ...what returns `tuples` first? A list? try to wrap the zip with `list()`.

Comment: Yes in Python 3 zip returns an iterator.

Answer (score -1):

My approach. List comprehension and no need to import modules. I think its fast, and its very simple.

EDIT: I've added an unsorted approach and a sorted approach.

```
#Unsorted
newList =[
    [item for sublist in Section for item in sublist],
    [item for sublist in Page for item in sublist],
    [item for sublist in Titles for item in sublist]
    ]

print newList
#Output
#[[1, 1.1, 1.2, 1, 2, 2.2, 3, 1, 1.2, 3.2, 3.5], 
# [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5], 
# ['General', 'Info', 'Titles', 'More', 'Info', 'Section', 'Here', 'Another', 'List', 'Of', 'Strings']]

#Sort first two lists afterwards, if desired
for i in range(2):
    newList[i].sort()

print newList
#Output
#[[1, 1, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 2, 2.2, 3, 3.2, 3.5], 
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5], 
# ['General', 'Info', 'Titles', 'More', 'Info', 'Section', 'Here', 'Another', 'List', 'Of', 'Strings']]
```

Comment: That's not OP's desired result since you sort the list independently.

Comment: @sparkandshine Ah, I see he said he wanted a form where it could be sorted afterwards. Thanks for the feedback. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make this clear, I only want to sort the list Section and the rest of the other two list should be sorted in the same order of the list Section after it is sorted. For example if after sorting Section the first few indices changed to 2, 4, 1. The other two list would need to change their indices to 2, 4, 1.